# How to detect the area of touch in open gl es in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have designed a 3D model in .obj format and imported using min3d framework. Its a cube with different colors. I want to give a Toast with a message for a particular color when the side of that particular color is touched. How do I do this in android 1.6 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the particulars in android/OpenGL-es, but *in general*:

You have to calculate a line that starts at the camera's position and passes through the screen coordinate pressed/clicked/etc and determine where that line intersects your object.

It's called... ah yes: "picking".  Googling for "opengl picking" turned up a tutorial or three:

http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/picking/

http://gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Picking
...

I just googled "opengl picking".  Those two are the first two links, the next is a FAQ entry, followed by another tutorial.  You get the idea.

Once you know what its called, finding information gets much easier.  Good hunting.