# how to detect touch event for 3d model in android

Tags: android, events, 3d

I am new to android 3d opengl. i have googled and got a sample code for implementing 3d models and animating the 3d models. Now i am struck with the touch events. I just loaded the 3d models into the screen and when i touch the screen Touch event was triggered and do the process with it but i need to touch the particular model not the entire screen. can any one please suggest the solution or any related article for touch event.

I am also tried API Demos for touch event which is in TouchRotateActivity but that is like touching the screen not the model which is in screen.

Comment: Check this,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278247/how-to-detect-touch-events-in-android , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942230/how-to-detect-the-area-of-touch-in-open-gl-es-in-android

Comment: Thanks for your reply, here i found Picking to find object which is under cursor position. can you please suggest some sample coding for this?

Comment: I never dealt with opengl so I cant answer u , better u check the ApiDemos to get some Idea